# Safari rendering table very strange

Tags: css, xhtml

I am trying to create a small todo application for a project, and it works how i want it in firefox. However when i view the website in safari and hover over one of my todo items very strange table borders show up. The hover also does not work as well as it does in firefox. Unfortunately for me the teacher is making in safari.

Here is the website link. 
http://webdesign3.georgianc.on.ca/~100128247/sem3/web_content/part2/

All help would be much appreciated

Comment: <table>, <tr>, <td> purpose is to display arrays of data, to create layout ans position content on website use <div>, <span>.

Comment: "Unfortunately for me the teacher is making in safari."

I would rather say you're lucky ;)

Comment: Can i add that when they are expanded(in FF) i can still see the corners of the smaller versions. Should this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Now your `td`'s have `overflow:scroll` and that's why scrolls show up.
You have to change it to:

```
td{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: wow i cannot believe i missed that! Thanks!.
Any ideas on why my hover does not function the same as it does on firefox?

Comment: It's probably because of default styling for tables in Gecko or Webkit. Don't forget to accept the answer :)